# Run Github Action as sudo

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using a [fastlane](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fastlane-action) Github action. I need to run it as the root user.

```
      - name: Deploy
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with:
          lane: 'alpha'
          subdirectory: 'android-staging'
```

How can I run this as sudo?

Comment: I needed to do this so that I could run a `gradlew` file. The solution was to [change the permissions](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/171#issuecomment-544447152) of the `gradlew` file instead of running as sudo.

Comment: `sudo` in GitHub Actions is passwordless (see [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges-of-github-hosted-runners)). So it shouldn't be an issue running command in `sudo`.

Comment: @FanchenBao: Is that still true? I had a github action using sudo that has run for years without issue, but this year it fails with "sudo: a password is required"

Comment: I haven't used `sudo` in GitHub Action for a while, so I am not sure if it still passwordless. The linked doc in my comment above no longer works, but I find [this doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges) that seems to explain the same thing: "When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more privileges than the current user, you can use sudo without needing to provide a password."

Answer (score 4):

As @itsjack mentioned, You either have to use `SUDO_ASKPASS` with a script that writes your sudoer user's password to the stream or use the actual `echo` command with `sudo -S` to make sudo read it from the pipeline.
I think it's much safer to store the password as a GitHub secret and `echo` it to the pipeline before using `sudo -S`; like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  Backup:
  runs-on: self-hosted
  steps:
    - name: Backup
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.PRODUCTIONWEBROOT }}
      run: echo ${{ secrets.USERPWD }} | sudo -S tar czf ./tmp/${{ format('Backup_Before_{0}.tar.gz', github.run_id) }} ./wwwroot
```

You can even use sudo as a user like `www-data` if you want:

```yaml
jobs:
  Backup:
  runs-on: self-hosted
  steps:
    - name: Backup
      working-directory: ${{ secrets.PRODUCTIONWEBROOT }}
      run: echo ${{ secrets.USERPWD }} | sudo -S -u www-data tar czf ./tmp/${{ format('Backup_Before_{0}.tar.gz', github.run_id) }} ./wwwroot
```

REMEMBER: the `USERPWD` secret must be the password to the user who runs Github's self-hosted service. I mean the user you used to install the runner or the specific user you used to install the runner service using `.svc.sh install USERNAME`

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#administrative-privileges

> The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless sudo. When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more privileges than the current user, you can use sudo without needing to provide a password.

Comment: Hmm... this seems to be false, depending on the action that one is using. For example, `actions/checkout@v4` does not have `sudo` permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Linux and macOS virtual machines both run using passwordless sudo. When you need to execute commands or install tools that require more privileges than the current user, you can use sudo without needing to provide a password.
```

That's not exactly correct. On Mac you can see this:

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

So askpass should be used.